# Manual Scion FR-S bucks or surges

Tags: manual-transmission, scion

I drive a low-mileage 2015 Toyota Scion FR-S that has a manual transmission. Lately when I first drive it I can feel a vibration in the clutch pedal just before I press it and when I engage it in second gear it bucks or surges a few times until I press in the clutch and then let it out again. As it warms up, the problem goes away.

My driving style has never been very good but it hasn't changed recently so I think there's some mechanical problem. Could it be the clutch has worn out?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very hard to know for sure through descriptions, but from the sounds of it your clutch is on the way out. One of several things which can go wrong with a clutch is heat cracks on the surface of the flywheel. What you're describing sounds like this might be the case. With poor clutch management, damage can be done to it even if the vehicle is of relatively low mileage.

My suggestion to you is to prepare for replacement. In this case, there is nothing which is of an emergency nature, so you can baby the clutch until a point in time which is convenient to you. The clutch as should continue to function, however it will probably becoming more annoying over time and with more wear.

Comment: That's a helpful suggestion. I am prepared to replace the clutch if needed but for now at least the problem has gone away. I don't know why, so I will keep an eye out. It's pretty hard to diagnose a problem when it comes and goes!